# Tomcat 6 loads wrong OpenSSL-Version

Tags: configuration, openssl

I updated tomcat 6.03.5 to 6.0.37. Afterwards i added the configuration to disable TLS Compression SSLDisableCompression="true" on APR-Connector. I also made a fresh build tomncat-native (1.1.27)

But on Tomcat start I thefollowing traces:

INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized with version **OpenSSL 0.9.8o** 01 Jun 2010
WARNING: Disable compression option is not supported by the SSL library OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010

System is Debian Squeeze with **OpenSSL 1.0.1e**.

So i have no idea why tomcat think OpenSSL 0.9.8 is installed (my previous version) 
Do i miss something, any suggestion?

**EDIT:**
Solution was to completly remove OpenSSL 0.9.8o an reinstall 1.0.1e after that Tomcat loaded the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to completly remove OpenSSL 0.9.8o an reinstall 1.0.1e after that Tomcat loaded the correct one